# Python Struct giving unexpected result

Tags: python, struct

If I use this code snippet in python I get an error

```
single_participant_info = "3h3hHbbbbHBBffH"
format_string = single_participant_info * 32
unpacked_data = struct.unpack(format_string, data)
```

error:
`"unpacked_data = struct.unpack(format_string, data) struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 1026 bytes"`

I think that single_participant_info is 32 bytes. 32*32 1024 bytes?
I've no idea how I can get an error of 1026 when that's not divisible by 32?
There always seems to be 2 bytes added.
single_participant_info on its own gives an error of 34

```
3h 3x2  6
3h 3x2  6
H       2
4b      4
H       2
2B      2
2f      8
H       2
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If possible, please provide a [mcve] so that we can directly reproduce your issue - in this concrete example, what is `data`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the welcome,
 Code to reproduce
import struct
data = b'\x00' * 1024  # A dummy byte array of length 1024
single_participant_info = "3h3hHbbbbHBBffH"
format_string = single_participant_info * 32
unpacked_data = struct.unpack(format_string, data)

Answer (score 1):

resolved with:

```
import struct
data = b'\x00' * 1024  # A dummy byte array of length 1024
single_participant_info = "3h3hHbbbbHBBffH"
format_string = "!" + single_participant_info * 32
unpacked_data = struct.unpack(format_string, data)
```

Python was adding bytes for alignment or padding, I think.
where "!" is Network Byte order with no padding, and resolves my issue